# Positioning and aligning many many matrices

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, positioning, matrices

**Edit:** I swapped `\begin{aligned} &\ro{r_2+-1r_1}\\ &\end{aligned}` with `&\ro{r_2+-1r_1}\\` , added some linebreaks an now it looks quite well.

I am working on a python matrix editor(it's still WIP) which outputs matrix equations as LaTex. In this case I tried to calculate an inverse matrix.
The matrices should align beneath one another, but the line continues beyond the document.

[image: Screenshot of the LaTex document in Overleaf]

I also tried adding linebreaks(`\\`and`\newline`) but it  didn't turn out as I hoped.
[image]

I want it to look something like this but better aligned.(This format doesn't always work, and causes a huge amount of warning/error messages)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\newenvironment{sysmatrix}[1]
 {\left(\begin{array}{@{}#1@{}}}
 {\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{%
  \xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[\rowidth]{#1}}%
}
\newlength{\rowidth}% row operation width
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\rowidth}{3em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_2+-1r_1}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_3+-1r_1}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_2\leftrightarrow r_3}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_4+-1r_1}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_4+-1r_2}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_4+-1r_3}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 1}{\strut 2} & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 1}{\strut 2} & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}\\
&\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & -2 & 1 & -2 & \dfrac{\strut -1}{\strut 2} & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 3}{\strut 2} & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

I'm still very new to LaTex and don't really know much about formating...
I hope you can help me.

Comment: what is the intention of  `\begin{aligned} &\ro{r_2+-1r_1}\\ &\end{aligned}`  a single row, single column alignment can't do anything useful?

Comment: And what does `+-` in `r_2+-1r_1` and other places denote? "Plus/minus", maybe? If so, it would be better to write `\pm`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it look better already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the markup, and squeezing the white space in the arrays, I also widened the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\newenvironment{sysmatrix}[1]
 {\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\left(\begin{array}{@{}#1@{}}}
 {\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{%
  \xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[\rowidth]{#1}}%
}
\newlength{\rowidth}% row operation width
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\rowidth}{3em}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\ro{r_2+-1r_1}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}\\
\ro{r_3+-1r_1}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\ro{r_2\leftrightarrow r_3}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}\\
\ro{r_4+-1r_1}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\ro{r_4+-1r_2}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}\\
\ro{r_4+-1r_3}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 1}{\strut 2} & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 1}{\strut 2} & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}\\
\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
&\ro{r_1+1/2r_2}
&\begin{sysmatrix}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & -2 & 1 & -2 & \dfrac{\strut -1}{\strut 2} & 0 & \dfrac{\strut 3}{\strut 2} & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{sysmatrix}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my main problem. I still got two little Problems. 1. If I use a lot more matrices, they continue beyond the bottom of the Page. I tried `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` but they don't work so well...     2. There is a blank page at the beginning of the document and I don't know how to remove it with LateX.

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` will allow page breaks. @TheBaum